# ¿Cómo resolver problema de ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value?

Tags: plsql

He creado un paquete con la función buscar_order que reciba como parámetro F_Order

```
create or replace PACKAGE BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG IS 
FUNCTION buscar_order (F_Order VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
END BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG;
```

La función se ejecuta como tal pero cuando el parámetro esta vació devuelve el error
**ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value** y de ahi no pasa aún cuando tiene una excepción.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG IS
    FUNCTION buscar_order(F_Order VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS    
    
    l_order  varchar2(150);

        Begin
                Select Flex_Value
                    Into l_Order
                From Flex_Values
                Where Flex_Value_Id = (Select Flex_Value_Id 
                                            From Flex_Values
                                            Where Flex_Value_Name = 'PROJECT')
                    And Flex_Value = NVL(F_Order,'X')
                    And Enabled_Flag = 'Y'
                    And Trunc(Nvl(End_Date_Active,Sysdate)) >= Trunc(Sysdate);
        Exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN   
        l_Order := null;
       
        end buscar_order;          
END  BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG;
```

Comment: En el caso de excepción no estás retornando nada, intenta ponerlo así: `WHEN OTHERS THEN return null;`

Comment: Muchas gracias, tambien me faltaba un return antes  de la excepción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta retornar sea el valor, que obtienes en `l_Order`, sea `null` en caso de excepción.

Por rigor en el código, y por claridad, te recomiendo que respetes siempre la sintaxis en que declaras tus variables.

En algunos contextos y programas los nombres son case sensitive, y declarar variables de un modo y usarlas de otro (no respetando mayúsculas por ejemplo) podría traerte problemas.

Así debería funcionar:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG IS
    FUNCTION buscar_order(F_Order VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS    
    
    l_Order  varchar2(150);

        Begin
                Select Flex_Value
                    Into l_Order
                From Flex_Values
                Where Flex_Value_Id = (Select Flex_Value_Id 
                                            From Flex_Values
                                            Where Flex_Value_Name = 'PROJECT')
                    And Flex_Value = NVL(F_Order,'X')
                    And Enabled_Flag = 'Y'
                    And Trunc(Nvl(End_Date_Active,Sysdate)) >= Trunc(Sysdate);
                    return l_Order;
        Exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN   
        return null;
       
        end buscar_order;          
END  BUSCAR_ORDER_PKG;
```

Comment: Buenas noches, necesito su ayuda por favor :(  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575937/funci%c3%b3n-usando-plsql