# Función usando PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

He hecho la siguiente función para quitar acentos a las palabras que desee para evitar problemas en la inserción de una tabla.

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEST (P_TEXTO  IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    
       l_texto VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
       
    begin
       
       select translate(P_TEXTO, 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU') into l_texto from dual;
       return (l_texto);
       
    end TEST;
    COMMIT;



Utilizo un proceso con este script para crear una colección en Oracle Apex y insertar en la tabla1. Existe una pantalla que tiene un file browser(:P2_FILE) para cargar un archivo plano **.txt**

Declare
   l_query            Varchar2(32767) := Null;

Begin
    
    Begin
        Delete From table1;
        Delete From table2;
        Commit;
    End;


    apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection('GL_UPLOAD');
    
    apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name => 'GL_UPLOAD');            


    l_query := 'select Limpiar_Texto(p.col001),
                       TEST(p.col002),---ACA HAGO USO DE LA FUNCION
                       Limpiar_Texto(p.col003)
                from apex_application_temp_files f, 
                table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                      p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                                      p_skip_rows                   => 1,
                                      p_store_profile_to_collection => ''FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION'',
                                      p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p
     where 1=1
       and f.name = '''||:P2_FILE||'''';
     
     
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
        p_collection_name => 'GL_UPLOAD', 
        p_query => l_query,
        p_generate_md5 => 'NO');
        
     commit; 
 end;
```

Así se ve la pag 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

****Al no quitarle los acentos a cierta columna el error que genera es que la segunda columna la una con varias(concatena) y la tilde la vuelve un signo --> ***¿***** y si se unen, se mueven los montos y no devuelve la sumatoria correcta.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Espero llegar a esto***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Configuración de la BD (NLS_CHARACTERSET) :** WE8ISO8859P15

**Definición de la tabla :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y q error te da?

Comment: que errorr te da? y cual es el motivo de convertir los caracteres si orcle admite utf-8, podrias dar un ejemplo de entrada y cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: He editado mi pregunta.

Comment: Es necesario saber la configuración de la BD (NLS_CHARACTERSET) y la definición de la tabla sobre la que operas

Comment: @Alfabravo he editado mi pregunta con tus consultas.